# Fast jackknife implementation in R

Tags: r, performance

In a simulation study, I must compute the jackknife variance estimator many million times, which is painstakingly slow in R when done with a for-loop (`theta` is the statistic of interest, for which I have used `cor()` as an example for illustration):

```
  theta <- function(x) {
    cor(x[,1], x[,2])
  }
  n <- nrow(x)
  jk <- numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    jk[i] <- theta(x[-i,1], x[-1,2])
  }
  jk.m <- mean(jk)
  jk.se <- sqrt((n-1)/n * sum((jk-jk.m)^2))
```

Is anyone aware of an R package, that implements the jacknife in C++? I have tried `bootstrap::jackknife` and `jackknifeR::jackknife`, but both implement it as R code and the first implementation is equally slow. The implementation in `jackknifeR` turned out to be even slower by a factor five, and the reported standard deviation is slightly different, so I would not trust its results (the error is not that large to be unusable, but it is nevertheless suspicious).

Comment: How is `theta()` defined (exactly)?

Comment: `theta()` is a call to a library function, so I have no control over its implementation. I will add an example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the speed depends on how you define `theta`. If it can be vectorized, like `sum` or `prod`, you can see a lot speed boost; otherwise, I am skeptical about the potentially huge improvement

## Code Example

```
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(1000)
theta <- sum # a dummy example for the statistic of interest

f1 <- function(x, theta) {
    n <- length(x)
    jk <- numeric(n)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        jk[i] <- theta(x[-i])
    }
    jk
}

f2 <- function(x, theta) {
    theta(x) - x
}
```

## Benchmark

```
microbenchmark(
    f1 = f1(x, theta),
    f2 = f2(x, theta),
    check = "equivalent",
    unit = "relative"
)
```

shows

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
   f1 3267.1 3424.5 5645.792 4066.75 6593.90 52337.2   100
   f2    1.6    1.9   18.873    5.10    7.55  1406.2   100
```

Comment: It seems that your example confirms my concern: That the for loop in the jackknife implementation is a bottleneck.

Comment: @cdalitz yes. if the statistic `theta` consists of many steps inside, you should vectorize the steps as many as possible.